# Neo4j build failing on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, maven, neo4j

I cloned master Neo4j on Github and tried to build it:

mvn clean install -DfullBuild -Dlicense.skip=true

Result:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Neo4j .............................................. SUCCESS [  1.917 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Licensing configuration .................... SUCCESS [  0.769 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Primitive Collections ...................... SUCCESS [ 43.278 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - IO ......................................... SUCCESS [01:50 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - CSV reading and parsing .................... SUCCESS [  5.461 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel ...................... SUCCESS [03:59 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - JMX support ................................ SUCCESS [  7.138 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Usage Data Collection ...................... SUCCESS [ 10.788 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Monitor Logging ............................ SUCCESS [  7.750 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Graphviz generation ........................ SUCCESS [  7.947 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Lucene Index ............................... SUCCESS [01:45 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Graph Algorithms ........................... SUCCESS [ 11.222 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Graph Matching ............................. SUCCESS [  7.938 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Community Cypher Build ..................... SUCCESS [  3.658 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Cypher Compiler 2.2 ........................ SUCCESS [04:34 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Cypher ..................................... SUCCESS [04:29 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Consistency Checker ........................ SUCCESS [01:10 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Community .................................. SUCCESS [02:22 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Community .................................. SUCCESS [  0.079 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Generic shell .............................. SUCCESS [01:19 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Import Command Line Tool ................... SUCCESS [ 31.435 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Examples ................................... SUCCESS [ 34.906 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Server API ................................. SUCCESS [  7.443 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Browser .................................... SUCCESS [ 57.323 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Server ..................................... SUCCESS [04:31 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Test Harness ............................... SUCCESS [ 26.720 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Server Plugin Tests ........................ SUCCESS [ 14.821 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Server Examples ............................ SUCCESS [ 25.881 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - UDC Integration ............................ SUCCESS [ 10.245 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - GraphGist .................................. SUCCESS [ 27.983 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Cypher Documentation ....................... SUCCESS [01:42 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Cypher Reference Card Tests ................ SUCCESS [ 27.326 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Community Build ............................ SUCCESS [  0.077 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Graph DB Monitoring and Management tools ... SUCCESS [ 10.148 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Advanced ................................... SUCCESS [  8.685 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Advanced Server ............................ SUCCESS [ 21.165 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Advanced Build ............................. SUCCESS [  0.064 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Query Logging .............................. SUCCESS [  8.720 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Communication Package ...................... SUCCESS [ 18.359 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Clustering Infrastructure .................. SUCCESS [ 25.807 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Backup Tool ................................ SUCCESS [01:22 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - High Availability .......................... SUCCESS [24:19 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Enterprise ................................. SUCCESS [ 10.279 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Enterprise Server .......................... SUCCESS [07:02 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Enterprise Performance Tests ............... SUCCESS [ 41.132 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Enterprise Build ........................... SUCCESS [  0.056 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Integration Tests .......................... SUCCESS [ 49.037 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Page Cache Stress Tests .................... SUCCESS [  0.097 s]
[INFO] Neo4j Javadocs ..................................... SUCCESS [  9.582 s]
[INFO] Neo4j Cypher Reference Card ........................ SUCCESS [ 42.708 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Reference Manual Contents .................. SUCCESS [  4.565 s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Reference Manual ........................... SUCCESS [09:49 min]
[INFO] Neo4j - Server Assembler ........................... SUCCESS [  1.083 s]
[INFO] Neo4j Community - Server Assembler ................. SUCCESS [  5.669 s]
[INFO] Neo4j Advanced - Server Assembler .................. SUCCESS [  5.255 s]
[INFO] Neo4j Enterprise - Server Assembler ................ SUCCESS [  5.249 s]
[INFO] Neo4j Desktop ...................................... SUCCESS [ 51.900 s]
[INFO] Neo4j Packaging Build .............................. SUCCESS [  0.049 s]
[INFO] Neo4j Debian Installers ............................ FAILURE [  4.538 s]
[INFO] Neo4j RPM Installers ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Community RPM ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Advanced RPM ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Community RPM ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Neo4j Linux Installers ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:22 h
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-27T19:37:24+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 308M/493M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to build community installer/package for mac which I assume is the last on the list above (Neo4j Linux Installers) but is skipped because of the Debian Installers  failure, because it can't find 'debuild' command. What is best way to resolve this?

I have found out that the missing command is used to build Debain packages but can't find a way to install it on my Mac.

Not familiar with mavern; is there a way to exclude the Debian and possibly RPM Installers from the build on my Mac, if Linux installer does not depend on these.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of neo's [pom.xml](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/8c5067d0b0a2577f848440abba566283e7c0446e/pom.xml) you'll see this:

```
<profile>
  <id>neo-full-build</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    <property>
      <name>fullBuild</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <modules>
    <module>manual</module>
    <module>packaging</module>
    <module>packaging/installer-linux</module>
  </modules>
  <properties>
    <attach-docs-phase>verify</attach-docs-phase>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

You see that bit where it includes `<module>packaging/installer-linux</module>`?   The debian installer package is underneath of that.  If you remove that line, I believe the full build will not descend into that directory, attempt to build a debian package (or any other linux, e.g. redhat RPM).

Comment: Hi, Thanks, did not quite solve my problem since your suggestion also removes the build of the package I want. But it pointed me in the right direction; I just needed to edit the pom in the installer-linux sub directory to remove the Debian and rpm installers modules. Now have a successful build.